# Clone panel to external monitor

Tags: panel, linux-mint

I have just installed Mint 18.1 with Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Kernel: 4.4.0-78) on my laptop and on the external monitor I have no panel at all. I read somewhere that this might be intentionally so I can have different items on the internal monitor and other on the external. I have no issue with this as long as I can "clone" somehow the settings/items from one panel to the other. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to find a way to partially solve this productivity issue. After lots of panel changes and finds (to see what files have changed) I noticed that the panel information is stored here:

```
~/.cinnamon/configs/panel-launchers@cinnamon.org
```

There are 2 .json files (one called 2.json for the main panel and another one called 30.json for the panel on the external monitor) and by copying the contents of one panel to another, I managed to clone the applications from the left to the right side.

**Note 1**: this is only a partial fix because I could only clone the launcher part of the panel and not the full panel, but this partial solution solves my problem

**Note 2**: I've tried soft linking these files but I managed to make the changes only one way (from one panel to another), so soft linking the files is not an option. Hardlink doesn't have any automated effects

**Note 3**: I'm not sure how the filenames are assigned on the panels but I assume they follow some convention-over-configuration naming policy because I couldn't find the names mentioned anywhere on the ~/.cinnamon folder

Answer (score 0):

The settings are actually not stored in files, they are stored in the dconf settings registry.

> Note: Changing these values manually can cause Cinnamon crashes if not careful.

Install `dconf-editor` and have a look at these registry keys: `/org/cinnamon/panel*`.

To change them programmatically, use the `dconf` CLI tool.

The applets added to a panel each have an ID that is used in `/org/cinnamon/enabled-applets` and similar keys and correspond to the filenames.

For the applet `'panel1:left:0:menu@cinnamon.org:15'`, the ID is `15`, for which the configuration would be located at `~/.config/cinnamon/spices/menu@cinnamon.org/15.json`.